# Google Chrome Inspector regex to filter JPG files

Tags: regex, google-chrome, grep, inspector

i am trying to use Google Chrome's Inspector 'Network' tab to find any assets in this format:
/content/dam/stb/lots/ANYTHING.jpg

This part is always the same /content/dam/stb/lots/ and spits out multiple image formats, i am trying to only display the ones in JPG format.

Actually tried `/content/dam/stb/lots/.*\.jpg`. It works but also displays results like `/content/dam/stb/lots/L16/L16143/086L16143_9343V.jpg.thumb.3‌​85.385.png` which contain the JPG string, but are not useful to me since they are ending in PNG. I only need strings ending in JPG no matter what.

Comment: The easiest pattern - `/content/dam/stb/lots/.*\.jpg`, have you tried it?

Comment: Actually tried that one. It works but also displays results like /content/dam/stb/lots/L16/L16143/086L16143_9343V.jpg.thumb.385.385.png which contain the JPG string, but are not useful to me since they are ending in PNG. I only need strings ending in JPG no matter what. thanks

Comment: Try `/content/dam/stb/lots/.*?\.jpg\b(?!\.)` or `/content/dam/stb/lots/.*?\.jpg(?!\S)`, or if the `.jpg` must come only after `/content/dam/stb/lots/` and characters other than `/`, use `/content/dam/stb/lots/[^\/]*\.jpg`

Comment: Please let know which one worked so that I could post and explain

Comment: This one seems to give me what i needed /content/dam/stb/lots/.*?\.jpg\b(?!\.)

Comment: Ok, let me explain in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content you have includes strings containing `.jpg` inside longer strings, and it seem the ones you want to exlude are the cases when `.jpg` is followed with a dot.

I suggest using a [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) with a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\.)`:

```
/content/dam/stb/lots/.*?\.jpg\b(?!\.)
                              ^^^^^^^^
```

This way, `.jpg` will be matched anywhere on the *line* after 0+ chars (`.*?`, lazy matching construct) when it is followed with a non-word char (or end of string) not followed with a literal dot.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I am also using Indesign, so the link you posted http://www.regular-expressions.info/ might be a good read.

Comment: I think [this page](http://www.jongware.com/idgrephelp.html) can also be of interest then.